# Assigning an Excel Chart Object Name with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to assign an Excel Chart Object name to a chart I am creating with XlsxWriter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (unintentionally) undocumented but you can set the object name for a chart when you create it. Like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column',
                            'name': 'MyChart'})  # Setting the name.

worksheet.write_row('A1', [1, 2, 3, 2, 1])

# Configure the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('A3', chart)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Update**: It is [documented](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-add-chart) now.